# Alternative for jQuery attr() in IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, attr

Ok, correct me if I'm wrong, but I take it that jQuery `attr()` does NOT work in IE. ([marked wontfix](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8900)) That being the case, what is the best alternative? For example, this works everywhere but IE:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.airsrc').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var src = $this.attr('data-websrc');
        $this.attr('src', src);
    });
});
```

**Update:** Whoops...I realize the issue. I actually had this inside an `if` statement based on a CSS3 media query. Media queries that aren't natively supported in IE8 or lower. The `attr()` definitely works!

Comment: I think attr('src') works... but using your own attributes don't.

Comment: That bug report specifically refers to 'event' attributes, like 'onchange'.. To my knowledge, attr('xx') should work fine in IE.

Comment: You're right. I mean for custom data attributes.

Comment: @ryanve: Custom data attributes work just fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I use `attr` with `data-*` attributes on IE all the time, I've never had a problem. [Here's a live version](http://jsbin.com/iyoqum), just tested in IE6, IE7, and IE9. Don't have my IE8 box handy, but again, I've never had a problem.

Comment: I realize the issue. I had it inside an `if` statement that was based on a CSS3 media query. It's the media queries that aren't natively supported in IE8 or lower. Thanks for the working example!

Answer (score 5):

I haven't had a problem with `attr()` working in IE. The description of the bug listed is:

> JQuery function .attr does not works under IE, when attribute is event
>   like .attr("onchange","alert('Hello event onchange!')"); . It is
>   because IE does not understand this. You can check, if attribute is
>   event, make eval function if IE.

Specifically, it has to do with *events*. Regular attributes shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 4):

please try this:

`$this.data('websrc');` instead of `$this.attr('data-websrc');`

Comment: Either should work. Using `data` to access `data-*` attributes just adds a layer of complication.

Comment: @abdullah Both of those definitely work in FF/Chrome/Safari/Opera but neither seem to work in IE.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder Thanks for ur comment. I know that. but I suggest OP to just use this, if the problem can be solved.

Comment: @T.J. Complication? Which method do you think is faster?

Comment: @ryanve: I doubt either is *measurably* faster in a normal use case, you'd have to be doing a really tight loop to notice, but jQuery's `data` goes beyond just the `data-*` attributes (see the docs for details). At best, `data` is going to eventually do what `attr` does anyway, hence my going through `attr` directly.

Comment: @T.J. Gotcha—that makes sense. I guess here the advantage is that `data()` just looks cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. I had some forms that I wanted to easily set whether the field was required or not. My form input looked like this:

`< input id="myid" name="myname" type="text" required="true" />`

It worked great in everything EXCEPT IE9! Doh!

The problem is that I do not want to set the new property with jQuery, and I don't want to extend the prototype for input elements.... I just want a solution that works in all browsers without a lot of extra code or branching.

I tried jQuery's prop() method, but again, it had to be set manually. I wanted something that would take all the DOM elements as-loaded and extract the data that way.

I found that the jQuery attr() method worked on all browsers except IE9. After poking at it for a while, I realized that the attribute was there but reading it was being handled a bit differently on IE9.

So, I ended up recalling the values this way:

`var val = $('#elementID').attr('required') || $('#elementID')[0].getAttribute('required');`

It is not perfect, but it worked great and did not require me to go back and rename my attributes with "data-" or to assign them after the DOM loaded.

Wouldn't it be great if jQuery 1.6.x would add this alteration to the attr() and prop() methods for us!

If anyone knows a more elegant solution that DOES NOT REQUIRE SETTING THE ATTRIBUTE AFTER PAGE LOAD, then please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that attr() will fail in IE if you use a mixed-case attribute name. Be sure to use all lowercase letters for your attribute names.