# change the href property with jQuery in IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, href

In a project I'm working on, I need to change the `href` value of a `<a>`-Tag dynamically.

So I'm using something like this:

```
var link = '/foo' // Some calculation to determine the correct link.
$('div.button-export a').attr('href', link);
```

And it works in every browser except - of course - IE8.
It just ignores the `.attr()` method or there is a bug or what. I need the fix this for IE8 and I need to fix it fast.

Do you have any idea what the heck is going on in IE8 and how to solve this?

**UPDATE: The full code**

```
var exportLink = jQuery('div.button-export a').first();

// TODO: SHOULD DO THIS WITH THE getExtent() METHOD
var data = {
    box:[
        GRD.mapController.map.extent.xmin,
        GRD.mapController.map.extent.ymin,
        GRD.mapController.map.extent.xmax,
        GRD.mapController.map.extent.ymax
    ],
    sr:GRD.mapController.map.extent.spatialReference.wkid,
    layer:GRD.mapController.shownCountryLayer,
    layerNoRegions:GRD.mapController.shownCountryLayerNoRegions,
    urlRegions:encodeURIComponent(GRD.mapController.config.country),
    urlCountry:encodeURIComponent(GRD.mapController.config.countryNoRegions)
};

exportLink.prop('href', Routing.generate('api_export_report_pdf', { "id":CI.report.cid, "data":JSON.stringify(data) })).show();
```

**Update**
Sorry for the confusion. Of course I used the correct selector. I just changed it a little. Still doesn't work.

Comment: have you tried javascript's version? `$('button.export a')[0].setAttribute('href', link);`

Comment: Try using `prop`: `$('button.export a').prop('href', link);` instead, assuming you have the version of jQuery > 1.6

Comment: having an anchor inside a button sounds like the kind of thing that might confuse something...

Comment: please post your full code .

Comment: No, there is no JS error. The `show()` method gets executed, but the `href` does not change.

Comment: This `$('button.export a').attr('href', link);` and This `jQuery('div.button-export a').first();` have two different `classes`, One is using `button.export` (button's class named export) and other is using `div.button-export` (div's class named button-export).

Comment: Have you checked if IE8 gets the code at all? Like trying css('background', 'thistle') just to be sure it's there. Sometimes we forget we are serving IE different code ;) 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7052182/alternative-for-jquery-attr-in-ie

Comment: Yes I tried that and it gets executed. Also, the `.show()` method gets executed. The `div` appears after a while and is initially hidden. So basically it works, only the `href` attribute won't change.

Comment: Does exportLink.prop('href') show you the correct current link? (before the change)

Comment: Yes. Well it shows the absolute link, but it's correct.

Comment: And if you write on the browser console: "$('div.button-export a').prop('href', link);" - is the link changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I was able to detect the problem. There was no real bug, the parsed DOM-Tree in the developer tool of IE 8 just didn't update, so I had to refresh it manually...

Also the link did not work, because there was a button inside and IE8 seems to have problems with `<button>` inside a `<a>`-Tag.

Sorry for all the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I think this:

```
$('button.export a').attr('href', link);
```

should be like this:

```
$('div.button-export a').attr('href', link);
```