# jQuery.attr('data-*') not work on IE8 (work on IE7)

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

this code on IE8 alert `undefined`, but Work on IE9 and IE7 (and FF, Chrome, etc)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('<object />').attr('id', 'stackoverflow').appendTo('body');
  $("#stackoverflow").attr('data-url', 'http://stackoverflow.com/');
  alert( $("#stackoverflow").attr('data-url') ); // IE8 alert 'undefined'
});
</script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

`jQuery.attr()` works on IE8 in many other cases, eg

```
$('<object />').attr('id', 'stackoverflow').appendTo('body');
alert( $("#stackoverflow").attr('id') ); // IE8 alert 'stackoverflow'
```

That would appear on IE8 there is a problem with some values ​​(eg url)

IE8 has limits with `jQuery.attr()`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7052182/alternative-for-jquery-attr-in-ie

Comment: This jsFiddle works on IE8 emulated: http://jsfiddle.net/zpao45a7/show/  The thing is IE8 doesn't support data-* attribute but i don't see how it could be an issue here because you aren't using the HTMLElement.dataset property

Comment: @A.Wolff Thanks , I did not know

Comment: One thing, you are setting attributes on BODY, not on the appended object, not sure it is what you are expecting. Sounds like you are looking for: `$('<object />').attr('id', 'stackoverflow').appendTo('body');`

Comment: @Sadikhasan thanks , but does not seem to have the same problem

Comment: @A.Wolff was what I wanted to do ...

Comment: I think you'll find all the information you need in [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dinosaur_behavior).

Comment: @Jonathan are you saying that `jQuery.attr()` is deprecated?

Comment: I'm saying you shouldn't bother with IE8 unless someone is holding a gun to your head. If that's the case, just patch the code and move on.

Comment: @Jonathan I'm asking: how do a patch code for IE8

Comment: Have you tried with vanilla JS? Or maybe IE8 can't handle the `-`, try naming the attribute `url`?